# How can a character be represented by a bit pattern containing three octal digits?

Tags: c, character, constants, octal

From Chapter 2(Sub section 2.3 named Constants) of K&R book on C programming language:

> Certain characters can be represented in character and string
>   constants by escape sequences like \n (newline); these sequences look
>   like two characters, but represent only one. In addition, an arbitrary
>   byte-sized bit pattern can be specified by

```
′\ooo′
```

> where ooo is one to three octal digits (0...7) or by

```
′\xhh′
```

> where hh is one or more hexadecimal digits (0...9, a...f, A...F). So
>   we might write

```
#define VTAB ′\013′    /* ASCII vertical tab */
#define BELL ′\007′    /* ASCII bell character */

or, in hexadecimal,
#define VTAB ′\xb′     /* ASCII vertical tab */
#define BELL ′\x7′     /* ASCII bell character */
```

The part that confuses me is the following wordings(emphasis mine): *where ooo is **one to three** octal digits (0...7)*. If there are three octal digits the the number of bits required will be 9(3 for each digit) which exceeds the byte length required for characters. Surely I am missing something here.  What is it that I am missing?

Comment: `which exceeds the byte length required for characters`. wrong. Machines _could_ have 9bit characters. Or 7bit. (or even 16bit) The '\377' are only constants, serving as initialisers. The compiler can  always complain if the values would not fit into a machine character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ooo` (3 octal digits) does indeed allow a specification of 9-bit values of 0 to 111111111 (binary) or 511.  If this is allowed is dependent on the `char` size.

Assignments such as below generate a warning on many environments because a char is 8 bits *in those environments*.  Typically the highest octal sequence allowed is `\377`.  But a `char` needs not be 8 bits.  OP's "9... exceeds the byte length required for characters" is incorrect.

```
char *s = "\777";  //warning "Octal sequence out of range"
char c  = '\777';  //warning
int i   = '\777';  //warning
```

The 3 octal digit constant `'\141'` is the same as `'a'` in a typically environment where ASCII is used.  But in an alternate character set, `'a'` could be different.  Thus if one wanted a portable bit pattern assignment of 01100001, one could use `'\141'` instead of  `'a'`.  One could accomplish the same by assigning `'\x61'`.   In some context, an octal pattern may be preferred.

C11 6.4.4.4.9 If no prefix used, "The value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence shall be in the range of representable values for the corresponding type: unsigned char"

Comment: Why `int i   = '\777';` should generate a warning?

Comment: @Geek  '\777' likely generates a warning unto itself.  It is trying to represent a `char`, but it is out of range with 8-bit `char`.  The fact `int` can hold 9+ bits is not the warning source.  one can do `int i = 0777` though (no `'`).

Answer (score 0):

The first octal digit is only allowed to go to 3 (two bits), not 7 (three bits), if we're talking about eight bit bytes.  If we're talking about ASCII (7 bit values), the first digit can only be zero or one.

If K&R says otherwise, their description is either incomplete or incorrect.

Comment: Why so? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You already stated the reason: a byte can only hold eight bits.  Actually, since we're talking about ASCII, the first digit can only be zero or one, since ASCII is defined on 7 bits, not 8.

Comment: I don't think there is any mention of ASCII in either K&R or later C standards. The character set is only required to accomodate letters, digits and NUL, IIRC. Much precaution was taken to support EBDIC et.al.

Comment: @wildplasser: Fair enough, but the constraints still stand.

Answer (score 0):

The range of code numbers of characters is not defined in K&R, as far as I can remember. In the early days, it was usually the ASCII range 0...127. Nowadays it is often an 8-bit range, 0...255, but it could be wider, too. In any case, the implementation-defined limits on the char data type imply restrictions on the escape notations, too.

For example, if the range is 0...127, then `\177` is the largest allowed octal escape.

Comment: FYI: Presently C11 5.2.4.2.1 "number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)" >= 8.  (CHAR_BIT).